# update texture_2d_array in webgl via twgl.js

Tags: webgl, webgl2, twgl.js

I'm using twgl for render some images in webgl. I need to dynamically add an Image to this array of 2d Textures.
I was using `twgl.createTexture` function to do this until know but there is a problem.
after I push some new image to my array of images and call `twgl.createTexture` to pass it to webgl and after that render my objects the images will not be shown correctly and instead of image a blue square will appear .
and when I manually render it again it makes correct and it will not break until use `twgl.createTexture` again.

I think that is becouse this function will make a new webglTexture instead update the previous one

I wants to know is there a way to update last texture with the last special array which has pushed some new image into it?

** when I say image I mean a base64 string or a loaded and cached url **

Answer (score 3):

as of v4.4.0 there is no way. twgl is just helper though, it doesn't do everything so you can always just do it manually.

```
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = resolve;
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = url;
  };
});

function updateSlice(gl, texture, slice, img, options);
  const format = options.format || gl.RGBA; 
  const type = options.type || gl.UNSIGNED.BYTE;
  const level = options.level || 0;

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture);
  gl.texSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, level, 0, 0, slice, img.width, img.height, 1,
                   format, type, img);
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
}

function updateSliceFromImage(gl, texture, slice, url, options) {
  loadImage(url)
  .then((e) => {
    updateSlice(gl, texture, slice, e.target, options);
  });
}
```

Comment: and when this ability will be added to twgl?

Comment: How do you use these functions you provided? what is 'slide' and 'options'?